# HP Printer not working on 23.04

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, 23.04

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 23.04 on hardware previously  running 22.04. Nothing has changed in the hardware, there is a USB connected HP Laserjet 1018. I used the add printer gui that Ubuntu provides and it completes normally. I tell it to print a test page, it says its been completed but nothing comes out. I also tried the same thing through the CUPS 631 interface with the same result.

The driver it selected is

HP LaserJet 1018 Foomatic/foo2zjs-z1 (recommended) (grayscale)

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a bug in hplip as distributed in 23.04. [BUG](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/2003739)

There is a workaround.